# Does using the Console Commands negatively affect me?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm wondering in case I get stuck in an area that I'm unable to get out of or if I clip into a wall and I suddenly can't move. I've had to disable clipping to get out of certain areas in Skyrim before but I want to make sure that things like my achievements and stuff won't shut out on my playthrough.

If I enable something, spawn an item that didn't spawn for me, or just basically use the console command to fix any bugs, what will happen achievement and game-wise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no negative effects to using the console. Achievements will not be disabled.

Source: Unlocked an achievement with godmode on (TCM), then reverted my save.

Comment: There's no negative effect *concerning* achievements. However, there's quite a few commands that are permanently irreversible (i.e., `setav`) and some that will even persist until you reload the game (the whole game, not just loading a save). Console commands allow you to break your save six ways from Sunday.

Comment: I'm actually going to downvote due to the sweeping "There are no negative effects", and echo @Mazura.

Comment: Also, console commands can make you feel dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that when you use it to spawn items it will add some IDs so spawning too much will add size your save and I tasted that myself when i added 9999 items it increased the size about "6 MB".
But except this nothing else.

Comment: I wouldn't call adding 6mb to the save file a negative effect..

Comment: Mentioning spawned item **save bloat** isn't the worst answer to this question. Plus one actually: there's a lot of ID lists for spawning all those damn components. Note to self: don't set X as one million for each of them.